# The EnforceConstraints property doesn't seem to work?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xsd, dataset

My boss has asked me to disable constraints for the dataset layer of our application.  Seemed easy enough to me, since the .XSDs had the EnforceConstraints boolean.  However, after turning that off I'm still getting the "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints." error in tests.  Any information/advice would be useful.

Edit:  Forgot to mention that this is using Visual Studio with the Dataset Designer.

Answer (score 0):

This is error not from Designer, this is error from Database.
In Designer you can just add another layer of constraint checks, but the main exception is from database.
Usually it bad practice to remove constraint because they are checks if Database contain correct data.